# IIS - 1 ApplicationPool with 2 sites, current_user is different. How to change?

Tags: iis, application-pool, iis-10

I got an ISS 10 server that host 2 PHP applications in 1 application pool.
The application pool is configured with an identity "userA".

When I run get_current_user() on site01 it return "userA".
When I run the same on site02 it return "IUSR".

How can I fix that for site02 and make it running with the same user account ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS Manager select the site and then the `Authentication` icon, select `Anonymous Authentication` and click on `Edit...` in the Actions panel on the right:

[image]

Make sure these settings are the same for both sites.

Comment: Thanks, now it is the correct user ! The goal was to be able to run Shell_Exec() but it is not working. I don't understand why but I'm not able to run a script with this site (it is working for site01). Any idea ?

Comment: @kent2004 - Sorry, I don't use or have PHP.